# UI-Router ui-sref to current state with new parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an app that has a location setting which when changed updates currency/ language etc.. This is visible on every page as it's in my parent state. When the location is changed using the below button...

```
<button ui-sref="{location: 'Europe'}">Europe</button>
//(which generate a href of 'href="#/Europe/home"' on my homepage)
```

the app should reload the current state and the suitable view and reinitialise the states controller using the new location parameters value.

The location setting button is in my parent state's view...

```
.state('root', {
        abstract: true,
        ncyBreadcrumb: {
            skip: true
        },
        url: '/:location',
        views: {

            '@': {
                templateUrl: function(params) {
                    return views + params.location + '/index.html';
                },
                controller: 'MainController as main'
            }

        },
        params: {
            location: null
        }
    })
```

My child states look like this...

```
.state('root.home', {
        url: '/home',
        templateUrl: function(params) {
          return views + params.location + '/home.html';
        }
}
```

This is working fine on the initial page that I load. The problem is if I load the app on the homepage(for example), navigate to another state and then change the location, the user is thrown back to the homepage(or whatever page the app was initially loaded on).

I think it's because as I navigate through the app the currentstate and generated href of the location buttons doesn't change to reflect the currentstate but I can't fix it. Is it an issue with how I'm referencing the current state in the ui-sref of the location button(not specifying a state and just updating the parameter in {})?

I could probably do $state.go in my controller through an ng-click but then I would be missing the generated href which we need for seo.

Any solutions would be greatly appreciated.